# Google Engine - NDVI time series by region - LineChart not connecting dots

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, time-series

I created a stack of NDVI images, and also have several polygon. When I plot the time series, points show up but only a few connects dates to each other.

I am using the ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion()

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fdelaralfonso%2FAPPs%3AExample

[image]

Any thoughts how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the option `interpolateNulls`:

```
var NDVITimeSeries = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
    collectionNDVIS2, geometry, ee.Reducer.mean(), 'ndvi', 10, 'system:time_start', 'id')
        .setChartType('LineChart')
        .setOptions({
          title: '2020 Wheat Trials Trials L8&S2 NDVI Temporal Series ',
          curveType: 'function',
          vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
          lineWidth: 1,
          pointSize: 4,
          interpolateNulls: true
        }

          );
print(NDVITimeSeries);
```

[link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/16f43267525f24c6300bfbec45188aa6)